# Add days to today date (widget wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I want to create a widget in WP showing "today date" + 1 to 3 days.

For delivery of products, it would show like this : Delivery time expected between date+1day and date+3days.

I would insert code in html widget.

Here is what I tried :

```
<?php $i=1;echo $date = strtotime(date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date)) . " +".$i."days"); ?>
```

But it doesnt show anything... maybe edit functions.php.

OK am bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP to do this, you're almost there:

```
$oneDay = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+1 day"));
$threeDays = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+3 days"));
```

So to echo it out:

```
echo "Delivery time expected between $oneDay and $threeDays.";
```

---

Remember that `strtotime()` returns a UNIX timestamp (like 130000485), while `date()` formats the timestamp using the string you provide, e.g. "d-m-Y" (like 04-02-2014 for today).

Comment: Well, HTML only is allowed in wordpress widget. So if you got html code, that would be really awesome! But if only possible with php... where should i put first code? (functions.php)? and second code in widget and make it allow php ?

Comment: Well I answered using PHP because your example code you provided used PHP...I assumed you already knew how to put the PHP code into the widget.

Comment: @Picsel you have to write a custom widget to be able to use PHP. But  creating a widget isn't that complicated. You'll find many tutorials online, e.g. this one: http://www.wpexplorer.com/create-widget-plugin-wordpress/

Comment: @Kau-Boy My knowledge of Wordpress is limited at best...I have almost no experience with it. I just saw PHP code and jumped to fix it :)

Comment: @David sorry, I actually wanted to mention Picsel ;)

Comment: @Kau-Boy Ah no problem, my friend.